# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

When i run the following program:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> AL = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_outaccountinfo);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvoutinfo);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> AL = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    DBOpen open = new DBOpen(Outaccountinfo.this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = open.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("outaccount", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String str_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                String str_money = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("outmoney"));
                String str_time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));
                String str_type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
                String str_mark = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mark"));
                map.put("id", str_id);
                map.put("outmoney", str_money);
                map.put("time", str_time);
                map.put("type", str_type);
                map.put("mark", str_mark);
                AL.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
    }
    String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        str[i] = AL.get(i).get("id").toString() + "|" + "  " + "money:" + String.valueOf(AL.get(i).get("outmoney"))
                + "  " + "time:" + AL.get(i).get("time").toString() + "  " + "type:" + AL.get(i).get("type").toString()
                + "  " + "mark:" + AL.get(i).get("mark").toString();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                str);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(Outaccountinfo.this, map.get("type"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

I receive the following error:

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Who can help me to achieve the purpose without changing the purpose of the program?

Thanks!

Comment: In what exactly line you got the exception?

Comment: @tts zhng any update of my answer

Comment: In this you are creating a string array and add to the adapter. When get data it will return string (in the OnItemClick) not a hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ArrayAdapter<String>` Means that you pass your adapter object of Strings.

Now, when you clicked on your item and asked for `parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` you get an `Object`.
If you will go inside this function you can see that the `Object` that you get is by position and by the type you sent to the `Adapter` (String).
So, when you try to cast that String to (`HashMap<String, String>`) you get the exception.

Try to do something like that after you clicked:

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); // Parameter in outside the click listener

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            map.put("someKey", parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Toast.makeText(Outaccountinfo.this, map.get("type"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

*****Can you try this code It might be helpful.*****

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvoutinfo);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> AL = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Account",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS outaccount(id text,outmoney text,time text,type text,mark text);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO outaccount VALUES('1','100','10','saving','80');");
    Cursor cursor = db.query("outaccount", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String str_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                String str_money = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("outmoney"));
                String str_time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));
                String str_type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
                String str_mark = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("mark"));
                map.put("id", str_id);
                map.put("outmoney", str_money);
                map.put("time", str_time);
                map.put("type", str_type);
                map.put("mark", str_mark);
                AL.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
    }
    String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        str[i] = AL.get(i).get("id").toString() + "|" + "  " + "money:" + String.valueOf(AL.get(i).get("outmoney"))
                + "  " + "time:" + AL.get(i).get("time").toString() + "  " + "type:" + AL.get(i).get("type").toString()
                + "  " + "mark:" + AL.get(i).get("mark").toString();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                str);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, map.get("type"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you include a few sentences describing what it fixes and why.